# Joining multiple columns to one column

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with two columns that I want to join to another table on one column.

- Table a: has `fkUserIdOpenedBan` and `FKuserIdClosedBag`
- Table b: has `FkUserID` and `UserName`

Both columns link to `FkUserID`

I need to be able to join them so that when I select I can see the username of the person who opened the bag and who closed the bag.

Do I need to create a temp table then join it?

I'd rather not do that as I will already be creating other temp tables in this report.

Comment: No, you don't need to create a temp-table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Hi I'm using T-SQL on SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join the table twice:

```
SELECT A.fkUserIdOpenedBag, B.UserName As OpenedName, A.fkUserIdClosedBag, C.UserName AS ClosedName FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON A.fkUserIdOpenedBag = B.fkUserId
INNER JOIN TableB AS C ON A.fkUserIdClosedBag = C.fkUserId
```